# OpenVPNで、外に出る分を通常のネットワークにしたい

Tags: windows-10, vpn

現在、自宅のネットワークがV6プラス接続になり、グローバルIPを取得できなくなってしまいました。
そのため、VPSサーバーをレンタルし、OpenVPNサーバーを立て、外部から入れるようにしました。
本来VPNは、
(1)...[利用環境]→[VPN]→[特定ネットワーク等]
かと思うのですが、現在必要なのは
(2)...[インターネット]→[VPS]→[VPN]→[自宅サーバー]
となっています。
通常利用時に、VPNを通過すると、速度が遅くなってしまうため、内から外は通常のネットワークを利用したいと思っています。
routeで出来るかなとつたない知識で試したのですが、知識及びませんでした。

```
>route print
===========================================================================
インターフェイス一覧
  7...14 dd a9 79 88 15 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  9...00 ff cf 41 03 8a ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  4...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================
```

-

```
(Interface 7)
接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.9
サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.1
```

-

```
(Interface 9)
接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.200.10
サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.252
デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:
```

7のNICが取得しているIPはローカルエリアのIPアドレスで、
9の仮想NICはVPNで取得しているIPアドレスが割り当たっていました。

方法を教えていただきますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `192.168.0.1` はなんのIPですか？